# Programmatically add 'My Network Place' for FTP site?

Tags: windows, scripting

Is there anyway I can create a small exe or batch file to setup a new 'My Network Place' in Windows? Its for an ftp site if that makes any difference.

XP will primarily be the target machine but If I can find something that will work on Vista too thats great.

Comment: You are trying to create a script that will connect to a FTP server?

Comment: No, I'm trying to create a script that automatically adds a network place to an ftp site. Then the user can drag and drop files across using windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this script to connect to a FTP using a proxy server.  You could adapt it for your needs.  It prompts for the filename and folder you are trying to access.  Just cut the code you don't need, and you should be good to go.

You will need to change the FTP Server Name variable as well.  Happy coding:

```
Option Explicit

Dim objShell, strFTPScriptFileName, strFile2Get
Dim strLocalFolderName, strFTPServerName, strLoginID
Dim strPassword, strFTPServerFolder, strFileToGet, returnCode


'Customize code here to fit your needs
strFTPServerName = "proxy.prv"
strLocalFolderName = ""
strLoginID = ""
strPassword = ""
strFTPServerFolder = ""
strFileToGet = ""




strLocalFolderName = GetLocalFolder()
strLoginID = InputBox("Enter FTP Username: ", "Enter FTP Username", "Authentication_Method@Destination_FTP_Host")
strPassword = InputBox("Enter FTP Password: ", "Enter FTP Password", "Authentication_Method@Destination_FTP_Host")
strFTPServerFolder = InputBox("Enter FTP folder that you want to access: ", "Enter FTP Folder", "/")
strFileToGet = InputBox("Enter the filename located on the FTP that you want to retrieve: ", "Enter FTP file", "*.*")

if strLoginID = "" then 
    WScript.Echo "You must specify a Login ID for this script to work"
    WScript.Quit()
end if

if strPassword = "" then 
    WScript.Echo "You must specify a Password for this script to work"
    WScript.Quit()
end if

if strFTPServerFolder = "" then 
    WScript.Echo "You must specify a FTP Folder to access for this script to work"
    WScript.Quit()
end if

if strFileToGet = "" then 
    WScript.Echo "You must specify a Filename to download for this script to work"
    WScript.Quit()
end if



Call WriteFTPScript()



Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
returnCode = objShell.Run( "cmd.exe /c ftp -s:" & chr(34) & strFTPScriptFileName & chr(34), 1, true)

if (returnCode = 0) then
   Wscript.echo("Your file has been downloaded.")
else
   Wscript.echo("An error has occured while attempting to download your file.")
End if

objShell.Run (strLocalFolderName)
Set objShell = Nothing



' **************************************************************************
' Creates the FTP script text file
Function WriteFTPScript()

    Dim objFSO, objMyFile
    strFTPScriptFileName = strLocalFolderName & "\FTPScript.txt"        'File to be created to hold ftp script data

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    If (objFSO.FileExists(strFTPScriptFileName)) Then
            objFSO.DeleteFile (strFTPScriptFileName)
    End If

    Set objMyFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strFTPScriptFileName, True)

    objMyFile.WriteLine ("open " & strFTPServerName)
    objMyFile.WriteLine (strLoginID)
    objMyFile.WriteLine (strPassword)
    objMyFile.WriteLine ("cd " & strFTPServerFolder)
    objMyFile.WriteLine ("lcd " & strLocalFolderName)
    objMyFile.WriteLine ("get " & strFileToGet)
    objMyFile.WriteLine ("bye")


    objMyFile.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objMyFile = Nothing

End Function



' **************************************************************************
' Dialog box to select folder to download to
Function GetLocalFolder()

    Const BIF_returnonlyfsdirs = &H0001
    Const BIF_editbox = &H0010
    Dim wsh, objDlg, objF

    Set objDlg = WScript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objF = objDlg.BrowseForFolder (&H0, "Select the destination folder to download FTP files to:", BIF_editbox + BIF_returnonlyfsdirs)

    If IsValue(objF) Then 
        GetLocalFolder = objF.ParentFolder.ParseName(objF.Title).Path
    Else
        WScript.Echo "You MUST specify a folder to download files to.  Application will now exit."
        WScript.Quit
    End If

end function


' **************************************************************************
' Verifies if the the object contains a value
Function IsValue(obj)
    Dim tmp
    On Error Resume Next
    tmp = " " & obj
    If Err <> 0 Then
        IsValue = False
    Else
        IsValue = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function



' **************************************************************************
' Verifies if the the object is a folder
Function IsFolder(obj)
    Dim objFSO
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    if objFSO.IsFolder(obj) then 
        IsFolder = True 
    end if



End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the script, but I'm not sure that its suitable for my application. The idea is that I can automatically setup the ftp 'dropbox' for the clients and then they can transfer files using windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The NetHood folder can be manipulated with vbScript. Refer to [this forum thread](http://www.pctools.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-47834.html) for more information. The following works for me on XP Pro:

```
Option Explicit
On Error Goto 0

'ShellSpecialFolderConstants
Const ssfNETHOOD = 19 '(&H13) Special Folder NETHOOD

Dim objWSHShell, objShell, objFolder, objFolderItem, strNetHood
Dim strShortcutName, strShortcutPath, objShortcut

Set objWSHShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(ssfNETHOOD)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
strNetHood = objFolderItem.Path

strShortcutName = "FTP to localhost"
strShortcutPath = "ftp://username@localhost/"

Set objShortcut = objWSHShell.CreateShortcut(strNetHood & "\" & strShortcutName & ".lnk")
objShortcut.TargetPath = strShortcutPath
objShortcut.Save
```